# Cannot find method execute() in Java Elasticsearch SearchRequestBuilder

Tags: java, netbeans, elasticsearch, dropwizard

I'm working on a REST web service in Java using the framework Dropwizard. Some resources will simply search for data in an Elasticsearch index. That's where I came to encounter a strange problem.

When using `SearchRequestBuilder` from `org.elasticsearch.action.search` I'm unable to perform search requests. This for the reason that the `execute()` method is not "available", as NetBeans (8.0.2) tells me by *cannot find symbol*. See this example:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("books")
           .setTypes("book")
           .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("year", 2015)) 
           .setFrom(0).setSize(60)
           .execute() // !!
           .actionGet();
```

NetBean's message:

> cannot find symbol
>     symbol: method execute()
>     location: class SearchRequestBuilder

I can perform index `client.prepareUpdate()` and get `client.prepareGet()` requests on Elasticsearch (client is of type `org.elasticsearch.client.Client`), so it's configured and set up correctly as well as the dependencies are working fine. When it comes to above search request however, I cannot execute the request since obviously NetBeans is unable to resolve the method `execute()`.

I have never experienced such behavior so I'm pretty clueless. Any ideas what is wrong or suggestions how I could perform search queries on Elasticsearch differently?

I'm using dropwizard-core-0.8.1, dropwizard-elasticsearch-0.8.0-1, elasticsearch-1.6.0.

Comment: How are you importing `org.elasticsearch.action.search`?? execute() is a method belonging to ActionRequestBuilder, which is in package `org.elasticsearch.action`. My hunch is that if you properly sort out this import, you won't run into trouble

Comment: I am aware of the inheritance and the package. To be sure I imported to whole package by `import org.elasticsearch.action.*`. It doesn't help. To me it seems like this is somehow a NetBeans problem, since I don't see how to import the needed classes/packages differently.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a NetBeans editor problem. Somehow the editor did not get the correct reference to the class/package and Javadoc of `SearchRequestBuilder` and therefore kept the project from building correctly.

**Solution: delete NetBeans' cache.**

You can see where NetBeans keeps its cache by going to *NetBeans > About NetBeans* and looking up the parameter *Cache directory*. Simply rename or delete this directory and restart NetBeans. The editor now gets the correct method definition for `execute()`.